# How to exclude the elements on Document click

Tags: javascript, jquery

**jQuery**

```
$(document).click( function () {
    alert("hi");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner-1">
    <div id="sub-inner1">Sub Inner1 Content</div>
    <div id="sub-inner2">Sub Inner2 Content</div>
    <div id="sub-inner3">Sub Inner3 Content</div>
  </div>

  <div id="inner-2" style="float:left; width:49%; border:dotted #CC3300;"> 
    content inside inner-2 div 
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show the Hi alert message on the Document click using Jquery. But I want to exclude the Inner-1 div and also its children. I meant that I want to get the alert message only when I click on the divs other than inner-1 and its children. Thanks.

Comment: How about `$('#inner-1').on('click', function() { return false; });` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('#inner-1').length == 0){
        console.log("click", e.target);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvUCc/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind a new event to excluding element like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e) {
  alert('Document got a click event');
});

// Here bind event on those event on which you want to exclude from
// document click
jQuery(document).on('click', '#inner-1', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).not('#inner-1').click(function () {
alert("hi");
});
```

reference **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#wrapper>div').not('#inner-1').click( function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xskVs/1/)

Comment: Will it also applies to the children of inner1 div?

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use Document object instead of #wrapper. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this one.

```
$(document).on("click", "#wrapper > div[id!='inner-1']", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

I hope this will help you.